# Looking for Regex

Tags: regex

I want to validate Winforms text box with regex.

The input sting example:

`ZX1 OR N?V OR 2L? OR ?55` (any sequence of three symbols length strings with OR between them)

What is the regex that you would advise?

**UPDATE:**
Trying this one but seams to be it is not 100% correct

```
string text = "ZX1 OR N?V OR 2L? OR ?55";
Regex r = new Regex("([0-9A-Z?]{3} OR )*[0-9A-Z?]{3}");
```

Comment: Please clarify. Are you asking for a regex that matches `ZXC` also `NV` with any character between also `BL` followed by any character?

Comment: Can you clarify the term "symbo"?  Does it mean "any non-space character"?  Or only certain characters?

Comment: @Ray Toal it could be any character including space

Comment: If your triplets can truly be any character including a space, then does the OR have to be separated by spaces?  That is, would "W3 OR A&#" work?  That is the three-char sequence "W3 " followed immediately by an OR then a space then "A&#".  So it seems to meet your criterion but looks wrong because W3 looks like two chars, not three.  You have to be very, very, precise here, but we can all help once the pattern is perfectly nailed down. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"^\\s*\\S{3}(?:\\s+OR\\s+\\S{3})*\\s*$"
```

should work in a variety of languages.

```
\\S
```

matches any non-space character, and

```
\\s
```

matches any space character, so the regex above matches any number of triplets of non-space characters separated by the string `"OR"` surrounded by space characters.

The `^` and `$` serve to ensure that it matches the whole string so you can take those out if you want to find this pattern inside a larger string.

Comment: this one very close but returns true for ZX1 OR N?V OR 2L? OR **?5**

Comment: @Joper, fixed.  I had a `\\S+` in there instead of `\\S{3}`.

Answer (score 0):

What is the list of possible symbols you can have? can you have at most one question mark?
This will match what you've given, but it will also match multiple question marks.

```
([A-Z?]{3} OR )*[A-Z?]{3}
```

Answer (score 0):

try...

```
(([\w\S]{3}\s+)or\s+)+[\w\S]{3}
```